# cannot read record from sharedprefences in language selection

Tags: java, android, kotlin

class LanguageFragment : Fragment() {

```
private var _binding: FragmentLanguageBinding? = null
private val binding get() = _binding
var navController = NavController


override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    _binding = FragmentLanguageBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, container, false)
    return binding?.root
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    val toolbar = binding?.toolbar
    val navController = findNavController()
    toolbar?.title = "Language"
    toolbar?.setNavigationOnClickListener {
        navController.navigate(R.id.languageToSetting)
    }

    binding!!.rlUnited.setOnClickListener { changeLanguage("en", "United") }
    binding!!.rlGerman.setOnClickListener { changeLanguage("de", "German") }
    binding!!.rlSpanish.setOnClickListener { changeLanguage("es", "Spanish") }
    binding!!.rlIndia.setOnClickListener { changeLanguage("hi", "India") }
    binding!!.rlItalian.setOnClickListener { changeLanguage("it", "Italy") }
    binding!!.rlJapanese.setOnClickListener { changeLanguage("ja", "Japan") }
    binding!!.rlPolish.setOnClickListener { changeLanguage("pl", "Polish") }
    binding!!.rlPortugal.setOnClickListener { changeLanguage("pt", "Portugal") }
    binding!!.rlVietnam.setOnClickListener { changeLanguage("vi", "Viatnamase") }
}



private fun changeLanguage(languageCode: String, CountryName: String) {

     val languageManager = MyPreferences.getInstance(requireContext())
    languageManager.prefLanguage = languageCode
    languageManager.prefLanguageName = CountryName

    val locale = Locale(languageCode)
    Locale.setDefault(locale)

    val configuration = android.content.res.Configuration()
    configuration.setLocale(locale)

    val context: Context = requireContext()
    context.resources.updateConfiguration(configuration, context.resources.displayMetrics)

    val intent = Intent(requireContext(), MainActivity::class.java)
    intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
    startActivity(intent)
    requireActivity().finish()

    languageManager.saveLanguagePreferences()
    languageManager.loadLanguagePreferences()
}
```

//Myprefences class
my functions and variables for the language in my prefences class

fun saveLanguagePreferences() {
sharedPreferences.edit {
putString(PREF_LANGUAGE, prefLanguage)
putString(PREF_LANGUAGE_NAME, prefLanguageName)
apply()
}
}

```
fun loadLanguagePreferences() {
    prefLanguage = sharedPreferences.getString(PREF_LANGUAGE, "") ?: ""
    prefLanguageName = sharedPreferences.getString(PREF_LANGUAGE_NAME, "") ?: ""
}
```

var prefLanguage: String?
get() = sharedPreferences.getString(PREF_LANGUAGE, "")
set(value) = sharedPreferences.edit {
putString(PREF_LANGUAGE, value)
apply()
}

```
var prefLanguageName: String?
    get() = sharedPreferences.getString(PREF_LANGUAGE_NAME, "")
    set(value) = sharedPreferences.edit {
        putString(PREF_LANGUAGE_NAME, value)
        apply()
    }
```

}

I provide multi-language support in my project, but when I make a language selection, my application translates, when the application is restarted, this selection is not read in the prefences. When I search chatgpt and other places, they explain that there is no error in my code

Comment: i'm not much of a kotlin guy, but perhaps it would be better to use commit() instead of apply() for confirming change success. also its better to get prefs in the onResume method and change them in the onPause method. kotlin has all these hippie bindings, but in java to make changes to SharedPreferences we'd have to use another object SharedPreferencesEditor. perhaps you might need to do that instead of set()? definitely try changing pref in the onPause method though